# Using preg_match in php to find substring given string?

Tags: php, preg-match

How do I use `preg_match` in PHP to get the substring `D30` in the following string?

```
$string = "random text sample=D30 more random text";
```

Comment: You don't need `preg_match()` for this. Just use `explode()`: `$result = explode('=', $str)[1];`.

Comment: exactly it could be done using explode()

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Please see changes above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) will assign the match groups to the third parameter and return the 1 on match and 0 on no match.  So check if `preg_match() == true`, and if it is, your value will be in `$matches[0]`.

```
$string = "random text sample=D30 more random text";
if(preg_match('/(?<=sample=)\S+/', $string, $matches)) {
    $value = reset($matches);
    echo $value; // D30
}
```

**RegEx:**

```
(?<=     (?# start lookbehind)
 sample= (?# match sample= literally)
)        (?# end lookbehind)
\S+      (?# match 1+ characters of non-whitespace)
```

[*Demo*](http://regex101.com/r/oD4dS1)

---

**Using capture groups instead of lookbehind:**

```
$string = "random text sample=D30 more random text";
if(preg_match('/sample=(\S+)/', $string, $matches)) {
    $value = $matches[1];
    echo $value; // D30
}
```

**RegEx:**

```
sample= (?# match sample= literally)
(       (?# start capture group)
 \S+    (?# match 1+ characters of non-whitespace)
)       (?# end capture group)
```

[*Demo*](http://regex101.com/r/lQ2mY6)

Comment: This demo returned "No match groups were extracted"... wh

Comment: I didn't use any match groups, instead I ***only*** matched the part you wanted..meaning your value is in `$matches[0]` not `$matches[1]`. I'll update with an alternative method.

Comment: Accept if it helped, I also included an example using capture groups instead of lookarounds.  I prefer the lookaround method when possible, but its good to be familiar with both.